# UnexpectedIdentifier in latLng

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to put together a HTML page that will run on my LAN so I can view some records in my MySQL db. So far I've sectioned it up nicely and I have it generating a separate XML file with all of my database records. Each record has a latitude and longitude. There's about 500 records; the XML is quite long.

I am trying to plot each of these records by their lat/long values with a Cluster Marker Google Map (v3 API). I have been reading the following documentation: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/examples.html.

However, as a novice I need some help debugging my JavaScript, and getting everything over that last hurdle! I have the following:

```
// MarkerCluster object
function load(){
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(53.37810447576022,-1.4622077941894531);
    var options = {
      'zoom': 7,
      'center': center,
      'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    // Create Map inside "map-canvas" <id> tag of HTML page.
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), options);

    downloadUrl("phpgenxml.php", function(data) {
    chop = []
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var latLng = new.google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("latitude")),parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("longitude")));
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({'position': latLng});
      chop.push(marker);
    }
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, chop);
  });

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}
}
load();
```

Basically, the map does not show at all. Can you help?

Comment: What javascript errors does the console report?  What does your XML look like? Is it valid?  Can you point your web browser at it and see the data?  What does your HTML look like? Does your map have a size?

Comment: That's my problem; it doesn't. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Yes, I can see the data (if you mean the XML file?).

Comment: Hang on, my bad! I'm getting an `UnexpectedIdentifier` error after the `latLng` variable inside the `for` loop.

Comment: You are missing a ")".

Comment: I can't see where. In the debugging tool of Chrome, all closing brackets are dynamically underscored as belonging to another within the function...?

Comment: My mistake, can't count, which is why I like to be able to run code.  Can't run yours.  If you address some of my other questions (HTML, snippet of XML), I might be able to.  You do have a "hanging comma": `position: latLng,`, but that only breaks some versions of  IE.

Comment: You have an extraneous "." in `var latLng = new.google.maps.LatLng(`, should be `var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(` (replace it with a space)

Comment: I since deleted that other `latLng,` line because I declared the whole line twice. However, it was the "." after the `new` that did it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extraneous "." in `var latLng = new.google.maps.LatLng(`, should be `var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(` (replace it with a space)